# fatal error: 'Fabric/Fabric.h' file not found

Tags: ios, git, teamcity, crashlytics

I am working on xcode 6.3.1, OSX 10.10.3 and I have configure crashlytics successfully with my local system. it work fine and it release the build via fabric app. But when I transfer same codebase to teamcity it was showing me following error

**fatal error: 'Fabric/Fabric.h' file not found** 
**fatal error: 'Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h' file not found**

After investigation, I found that following unknown issue in my teamcity server. Teamcity got the source from git and when I see the source code in teamcity,  Crashlytics.framworks & fabric.framworks are available but when you look into folder structure it could not figure out shortcuts for all headers, modules, resources, crashlytics folder (pic-1).

[image: without shortcut folders]

I get the other git clone in other folder and manually pull source code, here I can see the all shortcuts for crashlytics & fabrics sub folders. (pic-2).

[image: with shortcut folders]

I just copied all folders and pasted in teamcity source code. Now it works but every time when source code changed, teamcity reset to non-shortcut folder structure which will fail my builds. I am not sure this is GIT issue or teamcity or crashlytics issue. Please let me know how to figure out. I appreciate you answers.

Thanks
Manoj

Comment: Can you please open the Fabric.h and Crashlytics.h  file in xcode in the server and see whether there is only a single line of code. If yes ,reply back

Comment: Have you see [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-12648)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a Teamcity configuration issue.

When you include libraries, if using git to get the code you have to change the Version Control Settings.

Change VCS checkout mode to Automatically on agent. This will fix your issue. There is a problem with the teamcity git client which messes up the symlinks so the libraries dont actually download correctly.

Comment: Hi, How can i change VCS checkout mode to Automatically ?, What you mean by  VCS checkout mode ? , i don't know how and where  to change it

Comment: @adrian.coroian Is the setup done in my macOS PC? I don't see Teamcity in my list of applications... Any other way to set it?

Comment: @Vinayak Did you find what to do? If so, can you describe what you did? Is this done in my macOS PC? I don't see Teamcity in my list of applications... BTW, I looked for Fabric.h and it doesn't exist under my folder. But this didn't cause any problems on android...

Comment: @adrian.coroian Is the setup done in my macOS PC? I don't see Teamcity in my list of applications... Any other way to set it? 
BTW, I looked for Fabric.h and it doesn't exist under my folder. But this didn't cause any problems on android...

Comment: This was a long time ago @Yossi but i think this config i was talking about was on the TeamCity interface itself.