# Fabric.io Crashlytics and Answers initialization

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have included Crashlytics into my app. I did the signup wizard and initialized Crashlytics as instructed like so `[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];` in my `AppDelegate.m`

What do I need to do to initialize Answers and what the best place to do so in my app? I just want the basic initialization for right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For basic metrics, you need to include the Answers Kit from your plugin to use Answers!

---

**For Initialize Answers with Fabric**

```
//AppDelegate.m

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Fabric/Fabric.h>
#import <Answers/Answers.h>
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [Fabric with:@[[Answers class]]];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

[image][image]

---

**For Track Key Metric**

Answers can track key metrics in your app like tweets composed, songs played, and videos watched.
Follow along by copying code into your project to instrument one of your app's key metric.

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <Answers/Answers.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button setTitle:@"Trigger Key Metric" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(anImportantUserAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button sizeToFit];
    button.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:button];

}

- (void)anImportantUserAction {
    // TODO: Move this method and customize the name and parameters to track your key metrics
    //       Use your own string attributes to track common values over time
    //       Use your own number attributes to track median value over time
    [Answers logCustomEventWithName:@"Video Played" customAttributes:@{@"Category":@"Comedy",
                                                                       @"Length":@350}];
}


@end
```

Once you initialise successfully, answer tab show you App and Key Metric
[image]

Comment: For some reason the first "Initialize Answers with Fabric" didn't show up, but it did with Crashlytics. Maybe I didn't see it.

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs For both you can use like this -> [Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class],[Answers class]]];

Comment: @VineetChoudhary I am getting an error saying 'Fabric/Fabric.h' file not found. I saw in another SO question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29923807/fatal-error-fabric-fabric-h-file-not-found) that I need to configure Teamcity, which I don't have installed. Do you use Teamcity? Any idea how to solve this problem without Teamcity?

Comment: @Yossi I don't use TeamCity. I used self-hosted Jenkins with AppBox (https://getappbox.com) with Gitlab and I never faced this kind of issues. If it's work in my system 99% of the time it'll work on Jenkins too. Sometimes I forget to update the private key. :P

Comment: @VineetChoudhary Thanks. Still stuck in my build... No idea how to solve it :(